# Command button rerender not working when there are other components under Apex:form tag

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I am trying to learn about Visualforce pages, so consider me as a beginner :)

The scenario I am stuck in, is as below:

I am trying to re-render an outputText component on click of the command button.
When there is only command button component under the apex form tag, the rerender is working as expected for the outputText component.
But when i add one more component into the apex form tag, the rerender is not working and also, I could not see any method calls to the controller in the debug log.

The implemented piece of code will look something like this:

```
<apex:form>
   Select Fruit:
       <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedFruit}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!fruitsList}">
                        </apex:selectOptions>
        </apex:selectList> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                
   <apex:commandButton value="Get Price" action="{!getPrice}" rerender="output" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;
</apex:form>


<apex:outputPanel id="output">
     <apex:outputText rendered="{!renderedFlag}" value="{!price}" label="price"> 
     </apex:outputText>
                &nbsp;
</apex:outputPanel>
```

When the apex:selectList component is not present, outputPanel/outputText is working as expected by rerendering, but when that component present, rerender for outputPanel/outputText doesn't take place and even the method call.

Need your help to see why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I was sending the incorrect"value" parameter in the 'selectList' / was referencing a different parameter instead of the parameter set by the action attribute and my understanding of getter and setter methods was incorrect.

The value that is set in the value attribute of selectList should be set in the controller with getter and setter methods and that variable should be referenced in the controller.

The sample is as below:

```
public static String selectedFruit{get;set;}
```

When the button is clicked, the **selectedFruit value in the controller** is set via the **selectList action attribute**.